# Removing a very sticky masking tape on motorcycle body

Tags: adhesive

Good day to all.

This question is quite similar with this [one on this site,](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/13580/how-can-i-remove-hardened-masking-tape-on-car-surface) though this one is not yet hardened but just so sticky. I bought this motorcycle a week ago and they put some kind of mark to it using a very sticky masking tape (made of paper). Now, the tape is attached to it and I cannot remove it out without using brute force, such as knife. I don't want to scratch the paint in it.

The surface in which the tape adheres is made of very hard and dense plastic.

Is there a way I can remove it safely?

[image: Image of motor body.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Organic solvents should do it, but start with the mildest, to avoid damaging paint and plastic. **N.B.** Most of the following are flammable, and some are mildly toxic, so use *outdoors*, *away from flames*.

Rubbing alcohol, such as 90% or stronger isopropanol, is quite mild, though not very effective.

Diethyl ether is a bit more effective and will loosen masking tape, **but it is easily ignited**. Even a warm engine or muffler can cause it to burn. A comparatively safe source is [engine starting fluid](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001Q4DX9E) [usually available locally for less than that in the link]. Because the spray valve closes when released, it is less likely to cause flashback (flames jumping to the container).

Chlorinated solvents such as some [brake cleaner sprays](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000LDR9HI) are less flammable but more toxic. These solvents are more aggressive and might attack paint and plastics, so test in an inconspicuous spot before using on the tape.

Comment: Should I leave it overnight? or scratch immediately? I am not sure if leaving them overnight will not fade the paint.

Comment: A minute should be sufficient; in fact, ether will evaporate in just a few seconds. You may need to make a pad of some paper toweling covered by plastic wrap to keep the solvents from evaporating too fast.